# Why is this relation recursive?

Tags: logic, relations, computability

A relation $R \subset \mathbb{N}^d$ is called recursive if there exists a [primitive recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) f with
$$ (x_1 ,\dots,x_d) \in R \Leftrightarrow f(x_1,\dots,x_d)=0.$$

In Kurt Gödel's article 'Über formal unentscheidbare Sätze der Principia Mathematica und verwandter Systeme I', he proves the following proposition IV:

Assume $f : \mathbb{N}^n \to \mathbb{N}$ is a recursive function and $R \subset \mathbb{N}^{m+1}$ is a recursive relation. Then, the relation $S \subset \mathbb{N}^{n+m}$ 
$$ (a,b)\in S :\Leftrightarrow \exists x\in \mathbb{N} \text{ with }x \leq f(a)  \text{ and } (x,b)\in R  $$
with $a=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $b=(y_1,\dots,y_m)$, is also recursive.

After this proposition he claims that it is clear that $U \subset \mathbb{N}^2$ 
$$ (x_1,x_2)\in U :\Leftrightarrow  \exists x\in \mathbb{N} \text{ with }x \leq x_1  \text{ and } x_1 = x_2\cdot x $$
is a recursive relation. However, I do not see that this follows from proposition IV because the relation $R$ should only depend on $(x,x_2)$ not on $(x,x_1,x_2)$.

Is it still possible to show that $U$ is a recursive relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of proposition IV  the relation $S$ definied by

$$ (x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2) \in S : \Leftrightarrow \exists z\in \mathbb{N} \text{ with } z \leq x_1 \text{ and } y_1 = y_2 \cdot z $$
is recursive. Therefore, it exists a recursive function $f$ with
$$  (x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2) \in S \Leftrightarrow f(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2) = 0 .$$
Since $g(x,y):=f(x,y,x,y)$ is a recursive function, we have that the relation $U$ defined by
$$ (x,y) \in U :\Leftrightarrow (x,y,x,y) \in S \Leftrightarrow g(x,y)=0 $$
is recursive.